# The use of multiple sed statements on the command line

Tags: text-processing, sed, pipe

I am using the command below to output a list of IP addresses on the one line with the statement "working IP" after each IP

```
cat eciremoteExec1.txt | sort | uniq -c | awk -F " " '{print $3}' | sed 's/$/ working IP/'  | sed -e '0,/ working IP/ s/ working IP//' | sed '$ d' | paste -s -d ' ' | sed 's/working IP$//'
```

The output looks like this:

```
147.123.41.112 working IP 129.138.70.113 working IP 173.230.45.54 working 
IP 133.218.250.56 working IP 136.203.152.128 working IP 117.22.29.254 
working IP 117.3.11.111 working IP 127.59.131.236
```

I piped it into sed multiple times to get it to look as I wanted. Is there a better approach than using sed multiple times?

Comment: Advise what the file contains... post some data of file.

Comment: You can run multiple sed operations in a single `sed` call.

Answer (score 3):

It's not only about combining multiple `sed` commands (Jasen expained that part in his answer). You can learn some more:

```
cat file | sort ...
```

`cat` is not needed, as you can give `sort` a filename, you don't need to `cat` before, but do

```
sort file | uniq -c | awk ...
```

`uniq -c` is removes duplicates and adds a count, but as the following `awk` uses only the third comlun, so the count is dropped anyhow. You can drop the `-c` and replace the whole `uniq` with option `-u` to `sort`:

```
sort -u file | awk -F " " '{print $2}' | sed ...
```

Here you are misusing `awk` for `cut -d" " -f 2`, but you are free to do so. But now you can continue to use `awk` or do that step in `sed`, too. No need to switch tools for a task that can be equally done in each tool:

```
sort -u file | sed 's/[^ ]* *\([^ ]*\).*/\1 working IP/' ...
```

Here it's starting to be weird without knowing the input file. But if you are appending `working IP` to each line, then remove it for all in the range until it's first occurence, it should be identical to appending on all lines but the first one:

```
sort -u file | sed 's/[^ ]* *//;s/ .*//;1!s/$/ working IP/'
```

Next, the `paste` can easily be included in `sed` by collecting the lines in the hold space and later replacing the first newlines with a whitespace, all others with `working IP`. At the same time the removal of the last line ( `$ d`) can be done, so the whole mile-long command line with 6 different commands and 8 pipes burns down to a simple `sort`, only one pipe and a short `sed` script:

```
sort -u file | sed 's/[^ ]* *//;s/ .*//;$!{H;1h;d;};x;s/\n/ /;s// working IP /g'
```

Identical result without spending a lifetime to read options in `man` pages and analyze what is happening at each stage.

Answer (score 0):

it's probably possible to combine the first three sed calls like this

```
cat eciremoteExec1.txt | sort | uniq -c | awk -F " " '{print $3}' |
   sed 's/$/ working IP/;s/ working IP//; $ d' | paste -s -d ' ' |
   sed 's/working IP$//'
```

but it's hard to say without knowing what inputs are legal and what output is desired.